# What are stereospecific and stereoselective reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry

I have read the defination but couldn't grasp the concept, what is the key factor that says this is stereospecific or this is stereoselective and what are the main intuitions i can get if i am given that a reaction is stereospecific or stereoselective.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a question, ask it. You say you've read the defination[sic]. What it is that you fail to understand?

IUPAC Gold Book

stereospecificity (stereospecific)

1. A reaction is termed stereospecific if starting materials differing only in their configuration are converted into stereoisomeric products. According to this definition, a stereospecific process is necessarily stereoselective but not all stereoselective processes are stereospecific. Stereospecificity may be total (100%) or partial. The term is also applied to situations where reaction can be performed with only one stereoisomer. For example, the exclusive formation of trans-1,2-dibromocyclohexane upon bromination of cyclohexene is a stereospecific process, although the analogous reaction with (E)-cyclohexene has not been performed.
2. The term has also been applied to describe a reaction of very high stereoselectivity, but this usage is unnecessary and is discouraged.

stereoselectivity
(Also contains definition of: diastereoselectivity)

The preferential formation in a chemical reaction of one stereoisomer over another. When the stereoisomers are enantiomers, the phenomenon is called enantioselectivity and is quantitatively expressed by the enantiomer excess; when they are diastereoisomers, it is called diastereoselectivity and is quantitatively expressed by the diastereoisomer excess.